# Using MediaWiki note template in my MediaWiki site

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wiki

How can I import and use [MediaWiki Note](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Note) template in my MediaWiki site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Special:Export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Export) (with the "include templates" option) and then feed the resulting XML to Special:Import on your wiki.

Note though that copying a complex template is usually hard, you need to match the configuration of the source site to a significant extent for the template to work. E.g. in this case you'll need to install the TemplateData and Translate extensions, possibly Scribunto too.

Comment: What page or pages should I export?

Comment: Try the page of the template; if that doesn't work well try to export a few pages which use it. MediaWiki's template system does not play very nicely with exports (the system is only aware of what templates/modules are used in a given rendering of a template, and that might depend on what parameters the template gets) so this is not a surefire method but there is not much else you can do other than going through the sources by hand and taking notes.

Answer (score 0):

When you open [edit interface](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Note&action=edit) of that template, you will find a section called **Templates used on this page:**.

This section contain all modules, and templates that must be created in your wiki before adding this template.

Once you successfully copy that templates and modules to your wiki, then the template will work. Make sure that you install lua extension to your wiki also.

Comment: But there is a lot of templates and modules, isn't any easier way to do it?

Comment: No man, I am searching for the method till now from your time. Sounds expensive, huh? But also, if you got any idea, then please let me know also.