# Imported Template:Note, doesn't work on my Wiki site

Tags: templates, mediawiki, wiki

I exported `{{note}}` template from [media wiki note template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Note) page
and imported the `.xml` file into my wiki site.
but when I use `{{note|Foo}}` in my wiki, the page show following text instead the proper formatted Note:

> { "params": { "1": { "type": "content", "label": "Text", "required": true }, "2": { "label": "Type", "description": "'reminder', 'error', 'gotcha' or nothing. Will affect formatting.", "type": "string" } }, "format": "inline", "description": "Show a note in a box (e.g. a top-of-the-page warning)." }

Where is the problem?

**P.S:**
Importing and Exporting steps:

1. I went to [Export](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export) page and export [Note Template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Note):

[image: export steps]

2. I went to [Import](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Import) page and import the .xml file from step 1:

[image: import steps]

**Updated1**

I installed Translate and Scribunto extensions, too.

**Updated2**

after installing [TemplateData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateData) extension and using `{{note|Foo}}` in my page, the page show following table, instead Foo note:

[image: after installing TemplateData extension]

Comment: Are you sure you see this on the page where you use the note template (and not on the page of the template itself)? The [template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Note?action=raw) uses `<onlyinclude>` so everything outside that tag should not get included.

Comment: @Tgr Yes, l’m sure, I put this note on one of my existing pages.

Answer (score 2):

That is [TemplateData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateData) information. It is probably shown as plain text because the extension is not installed. As I said in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245046/323407),

> Note though that copying a complex template is usually hard, you need to match the configuration of the source site to a significant extent for the template to work. E.g. in this case you'll need to install the TemplateData and Translate extensions, possibly Scribunto too.